# Javascript - SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - while creating object - Invisible character

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, console.log, object-literal

I was reading the article on Javascript Objects (http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/), so I copy-pasted the following code into my Notepad++ and ran it in Chrome(Version 55.0.2883.87 m). Upon opening the console, console reports SyntaxError.
Does someone have an idea why? Everything seems ok.

```
// We have been using dot notation so far in the examples above, here is another example again:​
​var book = {title: "Ways to Go", pages: 280, bookMark1:"Page 20"};
​
​// To access the properties of the book object with dot notation, you do this:​
console.log(book.title); // Ways to Go​
console.log(book.pages); // 280
```

Comment: You ran it where? In a browser (which one), in nodejs, in something else entirely?

Comment: When I copied & paste your code to the console, I saw 2 invisible characters - That's the reason

Comment: Copy/paste can pick up invisible characters that will cause those errors. Just type the code in by hand.

Comment: `var book = {title: "Ways to Go", pages: 280, bookMark1:"Page 20"};
console.log(book.title); 
console.log(book.pages); ` Should work (without the invisible characters)

Comment: Can you explain invisible characters, is it because I copy-pasted the code. How can I test it and find invisible characters in the code ?

Comment: Back space the var

Comment: Open developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) and copy the code in your question in the console tab. Hit the Enter key, and then hit the `up` arrow key, and you'll see in the code red dots

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you copy everything you just pasted and write it in the console, you would see that there are some unicode characters (`\u200b`) in your code which are actually the `Invalid or unexpected token` in the error that you are getting, you don't see them because they are zero-width spaced, so just remove them and the code would run perfectly as shown below

```js
// We have been using dot notation so far in the examples above, here is another example again:
var book = {title: "Ways to Go", pages: 280, bookMark1:"Page 20"};

// To access the properties of the book object with dot notation, you do this:
console.log(book.title); // Ways to Go
console.log(book.pages); // 280
```

You can find more about the zero width space character here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm